# Install Mercurial Module for Windows Silently

Tags: python, puppet

I am trying to install the following package **mercurial-2.2.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe** silently to add it to my Puppet manifest.

I tried already with /s /q with no results.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a http://Superuser.com question?

Comment: This should help http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php

Comment: It seems that this guy https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg-winbuild/downloads/mercurial-2.2.1.win-amd64-py2.6.exe does not follow on any of the list of silent installers.

Comment: It does not do anything special: just extracts and (optionally) compiles some files.

Comment: Wondering if i can unzip that .exe using 7zip...

Answer (score 2):

A better approach might be to use the [Chocolatey](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/rismoney/chocolatey) package manager to [install mercurial](http://chocolatey.org/packages/hg):

> puppet module install rismoney/chocolatey

Then you can install mercurial (or most windows programs):

```
package { 'mercurial':
    ensure   => installed,
    provider => 'chocolatey',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial uses Inno Setup for their .exe installers. The option you are after is: `/VERYSILENT`.

They also usually offer .msi installers for download, but recently released packages are usually out as .exe before the .msi versions become available.

The documentation for Inno Setup command line parameters is at: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm

**Pro tip:** Whenever I'm looking for silent install command line options in a hurry, I read the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file for the chocolatey package.

Eg: for hg, go to https://chocolatey.org/packages/hg and click on the "show" link beside "tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1" (under "files") and look for a variable named "$silentArgs".